Hide/show fields based on a Boolean with JavaScript Dynamics CRM
Hi Stack community very new to Dynamics CRM development.
I want to achieve the following:

IF Validation Complete equals "Yes" THEN Show field Validated On && Set Validated On field value to UTC now current date, todays date.
ELSE Hide field Validated On.

cr253_validationcomplete is a YES/NO field.


Please advise.
 function showValidationOnChange (executionContext) {
        //Initiated Form Context.
        var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
        
        var ValidationComplete = formContext.getAttribute("cr253_validationcomplete").getValue();
      
        if (ValidationComplete === true) {
            //Using SetVisible propertly for hiding field Account Address.
            formContext.getControl("cr253_validatedon").setVisible(true);
            formContext.getControl("cr253_validatedon").setValue(Date.now());
        }
    }


Your code just needs some improvements, in particular the setValue should be used with getAttribute and to get a new date in JavaScript is new Date(), also the else condition is missing, my script has not been tested.
function showValidationOnChange (executionContext) {
    //Initiated Form Context.
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    
    var ValidationComplete = formContext.getAttribute("cr253_validationcomplete").getValue();
  
    if (ValidationComplete === true) {
        //Using SetVisible propertly for hiding field Account Address.
        formContext.getControl("cr253_validatedon").setVisible(true);
        formContext.getAttribute("cr253_validatedon").setValue(new Date());
    } else {
        formContext.getControl("cr253_validatedon").setVisible(false);
        formContext.getAttribute("cr253_validatedon").setValue(null);           
    }
}


is new Date() inputting the date the cr253_validationcomplete?

is it possible to show the field date as DD/MM/YYYY? UK DATE?

@Waq how the date is shown depends on the user settings, Dataverse/Dynamics CRM stores them as full datetime utc inside the DB, so based on the user settings the date is rendered (format and time zone difference)

How would I do also if Validation complete is blank/null/undefined then also hide Validated On? is the code doing this already?

Also @Guido Preite should this function be called onChange or Onload? Apparently if you call it onLoad the date will be set every time is that true?

my code also hide the field if is null ( setVisible false), if you call it on OnLoad the date will change every time the form is loaded if the field is true, maybe you will want to add a check if the date field already contains a value, depends on your logic

I just created a separate Function for onLoad to set ValidatedOn Fasle. Is that efficient? It can also be generically on the form if people want to hide fields just use this separate function, which is called onLoad only. Let me know your thoughts.
